# Blocking a specific URL accesser in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm a Google Chrome user and lately the browser redirects my search with a new format as specified "https://m.nearbyme.io/search" instead of the usual format for an http request in Google Chrome. Also I find the look-and-feel horrible. How can it be disabled so it will revert to the original ?


[the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi8f2.png)

Comment: Usually you just change your search engine back to Google or whatever you want via the Chrome settings, which can easily be googled.

Comment: Problem is that my engine is already Google Chrome

Comment: Google Chrome is a *browser*. I'm not talking about your browser, I'm talking about your *search engine* - there's a difference. Chrome uses google.com as their default search engine, but it looks like yours has been switched to m.nearbyme.io/search. **PLEASE** touch the settings button and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, **run a full virus scan** on your computer. These sort of search-switching shennanigans are typical of various viruses and other nasties. If this scan finds anything (or if you're simply worried), consider [the super user virus advice](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

If you're confident you're computer is safe, [follow these instructions from google](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) to change your search engine to the one of choice.